# fill in from previous command arguments

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, history-expansion

Can I make the right-arrow key fill in an argument-at-a-time from the previous command line?

```
$ mogrify -resize 50% file.jpg
$
```

pressing right arrow now should fill in `mogrify`, pressing right arrow again should fill in all the way up to `mogrify -resize`, if I were to press it again `mogrify -resize 50%` etc.

and in the case that the command line so far does not match the directly preceding command line, it should fill in from the most recent matching command

```
$ mogrify -resize 50% file.jpg
$ echo hi
$ mo
```

Pressing right arrow should fill in `mogrify` not `echo`.

how can zsh be configured to support this?

Answer (score 2):

The following code makes <kbd>Right</kbd> act normally unless it's at the end of the command line. If it is at the end of the command line, it looks for the previous matching history line starting with the text on the current line (it must be the exact same text, including whitespace). If it finds one, it inserts the next part of the matching line up to the beginning of the next word. With a numeric argument N, it pulls from the Nth matching line.

```
function immediate-complete-word-from-full-history {
  emulate -L zsh
  setopt extended_glob
  local line=${${history[(R)${(b)LBUFFER}*]}[${NUMERIC:-1}]}
  local blank=$' \t\n\f'
  if [[ -z $line ]]; then return; fi
  line=${line#$LBUFFER}
  LBUFFER+=${line%"${line##[^$blank]##[$blank]#}"}
}

function forward-char-or-immediate-complete-word-from-full-history {
  if [[ -n $RBUFFER ]]; then
    zle forward-char
  else
    immediate-complete-word-from-full-history
  fi
}

zle -N forward-char-or-immediate-complete-word-from-full-history
bindkey '\e[C' forward-char-or-immediate-complete-word-from-full-history
bindkey '\eOC' forward-char-or-immediate-complete-word-from-full-history
```

Known bug: this doesn't work well with history lines that contain a line break because `fc` outputs the line break as `\n`, which is indistinguishable from actually having `\n` inside the line. A fully correct solution would have to pull lines from `$history`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ah, neat, `history` has magic to make it expand in historical order. I should have checked.

Comment: This seems to fill up to a space instead of an entire argument, filling `/Folder\ ` instead of `/Folder\ Name` or `'one ` instead of `'one two'`

Comment: @theonlygusti Indeed, it fills up to whitespace. If you want to use shell words, you can use `words=("${(@z)line}")` to split the history line into words (assuming it's syntactically correct). Then you need to figure out how much of it to grab. A difficulty is that this erases information about the whitespace between words, and if that doesn't match then the history prefix lookup won't match if you press <Right> again. I figure spliting into words is good enough for interactive use: if you have an argument with spaces, you can keep pressing <Right> until you reach the end of the argument.